# Is there any way to implement this type hierarchy using the new co/contravariance in C# 4?

Tags: c#-4.0, covariance, class-hierarchy

Suppose I have a handle class like:

```
interface IHasHandle<TObject> {
     IHandle<TObject> Handle { get; }
}

interface IHandle<out TObject> {
     TObject Value { get; }
}
```

I would like to the use this class to give me the *most* derived output type in a hierarchy. What I have now looks like:

```
interface IAnimal : IHasHandle<IAnimal> { ... }

interface IMammal : IAnimal, IHasHandle<IMammal> { ... }

interface IFeline : IMammal, IHasHandle<IFeline> { ... }

class Tiger : IFeline {
     IHandle<IAnimal> IHasHandle<IAnimal>.Handle { get { ... } }
     IHandle<IMammal> IHasHandle<IMammal>.Handle { get { ... } }
     IHandle<IFeline> IHasHandle<IFeline>.Handle { get { ... } }
     public IHandle<Tiger>   Handle { get { ... } }
}
```

This means that when I have an IAnimal, I can always get IHandle, when I have IMammal, I can get IHandle, etc.

Does anyone have any general comments on this structure or ideas for how to avoid having every possible implementation?

Comment: Dependency injection?  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Even before .NET 4.0 it was possible to do things like:

```
interface IAnimal<TSpecies> : IHasHandle<TSpecies> where TSpecies : IAnimal<TSpecies> { ... }

interface IMammal<TSpecies> : IAnimal<TSpecies> where TSpecies : IMammal<TSpecies> { ... }

interface IFeline<TSpecies> : IMammal<TSpecies> where TSpecies : IFeline<TSpecies> { ... }

class Tiger : IFeline<Tiger> {
    IHandle<Tiger> IHasHandle<Tiger>.Handle { get { ... } }
}
```

Of course, this won't prevent you from making some `class EvilCat : IFeline<Tiger>`, but it provides quite a good way for getting rid of an extra unneeded `Handle` implementations in `Tiger`. And if you'll declare `IHasHandle` generic parameter as `out` one in this sample of code, you'll be able to cast `Tiger` (which implements `IHasHandle<Tiger>`) to `IHasHandle<IMammal>` for example.